# sdr as watts and amps

Tags: transmitter, amplifier

Thanks to rclocher3 for helping edit more to English

why closed
so
my struggle to get thought to English
thank rclocher3
I round back too
best I put
in avuenue what I was asking

**why closed**
i tryed
so

SDR's are low power output, as I know it

can you control the watts out on an SDR

is if you like more output power
use an amplifier

as if you respect max power watt output to fcc band plan,

By the way I'm good in math not writing(dyslexia dysgraphia, that not excess, I do try to do better next time)

```
[sdr out put] watts * [amplifier gain]db = [to antenna]watts
```

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: if you're having a hard time putting your question to words or drawings, often formulas help!

Comment: Hello, I took a stab at editing your question.  Please feel free to edit it further or reject my edit if I changed what you meant.  I'm trying to help!

Comment: how to exstep the edit somone did with note of them

and more sdr are low power output

rclocher3
thanks

so [W] * dB gain = [out put]

Comment: I Googled *dysgraphia*, and found that many folks that have it are quite articulate and coherent when talking. If you are, then perhaps you might benefit greatly from speech-to-text software. The resulting text could then be pasted into your question. Might that work? Just trying to help, as your question has now has three close votes.

Comment: Closed because the question was rolled back and re-edited by the original author so many times, that it had lost all meaning.

Comment: so why close
did not answer

roll back to what i put and one other edit

I do you tts and other aids

to many time
it was better

so can you control watt out put on sdr

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten that decibels are a way of expressing the difference of two things **logarithmically**.

20dB is a gain of 100.

So with 1W in you get 100W out, and with 2W in you get 200W.

Also remember that many commercial amplifiers talk a good talk about what gain they can provide, but they won't always walk the walk, if you see what I mean. That is to say that an amplifier sold as having a 20dB gain might only give 80W out for 1W in.

Also, since you are thinking in watts, make sure you don't overload the amplifier. Just because it says it gives a 20dB gain, you won't get 200W out for a 2W input if the amplifier itself is rated at 100W maximum output.

Comment: cam up set watt output on sdr?
i lack english duh
i try
so
ok then
stackexchange be prefix and have it have it , do not try it does not count

Answer (score 1):

I know you want watts, and in this case since you are adding just one stage (the amplifier) it is a little bit annoying that the amplifier's gain is in decibels. The reason for that is because when you have a lot of things to add, for example…

> SDR + amplifier - coax loss + antenna gain = [Effective radiated power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_radiated_power)

…then decibels becomes very handy. The trick I use is to start with my power (watts) in decibels too!

Think of a plain decibel `dB` unit like an increase/decrease *ratio*. But there are also [decibel-with-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Decibel&oldid=938548507#Suffixes_and_reference_values) units, like `dBm` (power relative to a milliwatt) and `dBuV` (voltage relative to a microvolt).

You can think of numbers with these "reference decibels" as *absolute values* — e.g. `0 dBm` is the same as `1 milliwatt`. That's because it's the reference **m**illiwatt (the `…m` part) with no increase or decrease (the `0 dB…` part).

Let's say your SDR is 0.1W. That is `20 dBm`, because 100 mW (0.1W) is a 20 dB increase from the `…m` reference unit of 1 mW. I made myself a little "dBm ↔︎ watts converter" that's available here https://utils.ipcalf.com/#dbm and you can type in your actual SDR watt in the right hand (watts) box and the dBM will show up in the left box.

I'll continue with a 100 mW transmitter for example, into an amplifier that has 35 dB gain for example. You can replace with your actual numbers. We know 100 mW is the same as 20 dBm. So now we can do your math:

```
SDR output (20 dBm) + amplifier gain (35 dB) = to antenna (55 dBm)
```

So you get `55 dBm` to the antenna. But the FCC safety limits and some band restrictions are given in watts on most charts. So we don't want `dBm` but `W`.

I put that back into the left box (dBm) of my calculator and it shows `316.2277660168379` on the watts side. So our example SDR plus example amplifier together output about 316 watts total!

Or to get Effective Radiated Power, we keep it in dBm for a little longer:

```
20 dBm (SDR) + 35 dB (amplifier) - 5 dB (coax loss) + 3 dB (antenna gain) = 53 dBm (ERP)
```

Converting to watts again, `53 dBm` is approximately `200 W` (199.5…). But it was very handy to add in more steps while it was still in decibels. You can even add more `dB` things, like your [predicted path loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Path_loss&oldid=936914768#Prediction) and a **receiver** antenna gain to [predict whether communication is possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget)…