# Can the power output of a software defined radio be adjusted?

Tags: software-defined-radio

Some SDR transmitters have a very low power output.

Can their output be adjusted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sdr as watts and amps](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16056/sdr-as-watts-and-amps)

Comment: You are asking whether the RF power output of an SDR transmitter can be adjusted, right? We can't answer that unless we know *what make and model of SDR* that you are referring to. There are many [different SDRs](https://blog.bliley.com/10-popular-software-defined-radios-sdr). Please edit your question and add this.

Answer (score 1):

All radio transmitters can adjust power within some limits, that's how they modulate the information they are sending.  Most solid state radios start with a very low power output modulation stage which then goes to one or more amplifier stages.  SDR is not different.

In the case of an SDR, it converts voltage on the antenna to an integer value from the A/D converter when receiving, or converts the integer value to an analog voltage in the D/A converter when transmitting.  Technically, this adjusts power.

If you want more power, you need an amplifier, which could be in the device or external to the device.

Any more specific answer would require a device model to see what its maximum power output is and if it has an amplifier.

Theoretically, you can have any transmitter transmit at any power, through either of attenuators or amplifiers.  Asking if a non-specific transmitter power can be adjusted is not really a very good question.